# unable to open uris or files with this app

Tags: release-loki

I am using `Foxit Reader` as the default `pdf` reader in `Elementary os Loki`. Yesterday I updated my system. After installing the `Software updates` which are provided by the `AppCenter` when I open a `pdf` the above error occurs. An image is attached below [image: below] . But when I open `Foxit Reader` separately and when I drag and drop the `pdf` files on it, it works fine. How to fix this so that it is able to open `pdf` files just by single clicking, which worked fine before the updating the system. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same problem when trying to use the Arduino IDE program.
using Loki 0.4. I did select the Arduino IDE as default program, didn't solve my problem.
The file I try to open is also not the problem.
I can open de Arduino IDE if I start if from the applications menu.

Comment: I have the same problem with a program called Logisim, it opens in Nautilus but not in Elementary OS Files

Answer (score 1):

You should try to re-assign `Foxit Reader` to `pdf` files.

In order to do so you can select a pdf file in *Files,* right mouse click on it to open the `Properties` dialog and select `Foxit Reader` in the *Open with* drop down menu at the bottom of the dialog.